# Unable to parse JSON array in Golang

Tags: json, go, decoding

I am having hard time parsing following JSON array.

```
// JSON Array
[      
  {
    "ShaId": "adf56a4d",
    "Regions": [
      {
        "Name": "us-east-1a"
      }
    ]
  }
 .... more such
]
```

Link to Go Playground :- https://play.golang.org/p/D4VrX3uoE8

Where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your original JSON input:

```
content := `{"ShaId": "adf56a4d", "Regions": [{"Name": "us-east-1a"}]}`
```

It is not an array, change it to:

```
content := `[{"ShaId": "adf56a4d", "Regions": [{"Name": "us-east-1a"}]}]`
```

With this, the result:

```
Results: []main.ShaInfo{main.ShaInfo{ShaId:"adf56a4d",
                Regions:main.Region{struct { Name string }{Name:"us-east-1a"}}}}
```

**Note:**

If you input is not an array, then don't try to parse an array (slice) out of it, just one `ShaInfo`. This also works if you don't/can't modify the input:

```
var data ShaInfo
content := `{"ShaId": "adf56a4d", "Regions": [{"Name": "us-east-1a"}]}`
json.Unmarshal([]byte(content), &data)
```

Output:

```
Results: main.ShaInfo{ShaId:"adf56a4d",
              Regions:main.Region{struct { Name string }{Name:"us-east-1a"}}}
```

Comment: Will this work if I fetch the content reading any json file with above json?

Comment: @ram It doesn't matter where the JSON is coming from. But if your input JSON is not an array, then don't try to parse an array (slice) out of it, just one `ShaInfo`.

Comment: Either this, or change the definition of `data` to `ShaInfo` rather than `[]ShaInfo`.